# Getting Attr (ID) of Dynamically Added <li> Element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues getting ID of a dynamically added list element. Which is being added with the following:

```
$(".detail-view button").on("click", function(){
    var noItems = $("ul#cart-items li").eq(0).attr("id");
    var detailID = $(this).attr('id');

    var orderTitle = $("#detail-"+ detailID + " span.order-title").text();
    var insertTitle = $("<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove-item\"><img src=\"/assets/images/global/intra_remove_item_btn.png\" /></a>"+ orderTitle +"</li>").attr("id", detailID);

    if(noItems == "emptycart") {
        $("ul#cart-items li#emptycart").replaceWith(insertTitle);
        $("#lp-orderform li:even").addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        $(insertTitle).insertAfter("ul#cart-items li:last");
        $("#lp-orderform li:even").addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

Which updates my original HTML from the following...

```
<ul id="cart-items">
    <li id="emptycart">You have no items in your cart.</li>
</ul>
```

And updates to...

```
<ul id="cart-items">
    <li id="6955" class="highlight"><a href="#" class="remove-item"><img src="/assets/images/global/intra_remove_item_btn.png"></a>Chicken with Garlic Sauce</li>
    <li id="6966"><a href="#" class="remove-item"><img src="/assets/images/global/intra_remove_item_btn.png"></a>Hunan Shrimp with Black Bean Sauce</li>
    <li id="6965" class="highlight"><a href="#" class="remove-item"><img src="/assets/images/global/intra_remove_item_btn.png"></a>Hunan Pork with Black Bean Sauce</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get the ID of the list item when a.remove-item is clicked to remove that list element.

```
$("ul#cart-items").live("click", "li a.replace-item", function(){
    var removeItemID = $("li a.replace-item").attr("id");
    alert(removeItemID);
});
```

But I only seem to get a value of "undefined". Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated from 1.7 onwards, and removed from 1.9; prior to 1.7 [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/) is recommended instead.

Comment: The `id` is not the attribute of `li a.replace-item` but its parent.
Try `var removeItemId = $(this).parent().attr('id)`

Comment: use `on()` instead of `live()` for jquery 1.7+

Comment: You're using .on syntax, with .live. Just replace `live` with `on`

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and started with .on but couldn't get it work so I tried live which started to work.

Comment: I've updated to .on but with the following code, still get not value "undefined". `$("#cart-items").on("click", "li a", function(){
      var removeItemID = $("li a").parent().attr("id");
      alert(removeItemID);
   });`

Comment: I've got it working, realized the mistake I was making with my code. Thank you for the help! `$("#cart-items").on("click", "li a", function(){
      var removeItemID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
      alert(removeItemID);
   });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update**

To get id of `li` on clicking `<a>` link

```
$("#cart-items").on("click", "a", function(){
var removeItemID = $(this).parent("li").attr('id');
alert(removeItemID);
});
```

***Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL8Vh/1/)***

To get just `id` of clicked `li` use

```
$("#cart-items").on("click", "li", function(){
var removeItemID = $(this).attr('id');
alert(removeItemID);
});
```

***Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzJzC/4/)***

---

Your `li` element does't have `remove-item` class , but `a` hyperlink have

If you want to detect on `li` item click

```
    $("#cart-items").on("click", "li", function(){
    var removeItemID = $(this).find('a').attr("class");
    alert(removeItemID);
});
```

***Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMQMA/)***

else if you want to detect on `a` hyperlink click

```
    $("#cart-items").on("click", "a", function(){
    var removeItemID = $(this).attr("class");
    alert(removeItemID);
});
```

***Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzJzC/)***

Comment: You are correct my li does not have the class, my "a" does and i'm not trying to get the class of my "a" I'm trying to get the ID of it's parent <li>.

Comment: hi if you got your answer then please set as answer for your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @pathaktejpal updated my answer according to your requirement :)

Comment: haha deadlock. i commented for philecker(who asked question)
i mean to say him that he should tick your answer as answer for his question if he got his answer. cuase on bases of that only you will get reputation. :)

Comment: @pathaktejpal I tagged you by mistake instead of OP. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

The element that you are requesting the ID from doesn't have an ID. Try this code:

```
$("ul#cart-items").live("click", "li a.replace-item", function(){
    var removeItemID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(removeItemID);
});
```

if jQuery 1.7 or greater you should use on instead of live like so:

```
$("ul#cart-items").on("click", "li a.replace-item", function(){
    var removeItemID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(removeItemID);
});
```